# How can I create something like routing on a websocket client in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, web, websocket

I used to write in js and everything was very simple. I had an onmessage function, where I received data, parsed it and got the route field from it. Then it was essentially a route. That's about it.

```
`const routes = {
  'route_1': () => {},
  'route_2': () => {}
}
...
ws.onmessage = (d) => {
 const data = JSON.Parse(d);
 if(routes[data.route]
   routes[data.route](data.data)
}`
```

And it worked great in JS. But what about in C#? I can parse json the same way. But I don't quite understand this. In the same place it is necessary to create a class that describes the incoming data. Like this:

```
`class Data{
  public string route;
  public string data;
}
ws.onmessage = (d) => {
  var data = JSON.Parse<Data>();
}`
```

But to me constantly the data different on structure will come. In order to know which ones you must first parse and look at the route field. How is it usually done? I can not find.

Comment: Could you add some examples of how your JSON would look like? There is [SimpleJson](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON/blob/master/SimpleJSON.cs) which allows dynamic JSON parsing without the need of a fixed JSON structure directly via field names. And in `Newtonsoft Jeon.NET` you don't need to implement the entire data structure, only the parts you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

If the question wasn't about unity specifically, I'd use the System.Text.Json parser. This parser can populate a `JsonElement` property with a partial json document so it can be converted to a specific `Type` later. A complete implementation might look something like;

```cs
public class Message
{
    public string Route { get; set; }
    public JsonElement Data { get; set; }
}

// define an interface, so we can manage multiple handlers without needing to worry about generics
public interface IRoute
{
    void OnMessage(JsonElement data);
}

// define a base type to simplify parsing
public abstract class Route<T>: IRoute
{
    public abstract void OnMessage(T data);

    // convert the data property to a specific type here;
    void IRoute.OnMessage(JsonElement data)
        => data.Deserialize<T>();
}

// then a specific message route handler / data type
public class MyData
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

public class MyRoute : Route<MyData>
{
    public override void OnMessage(MyData data)
    {
        // TODO implement handler
    }
}

public class Handler
{
    public static Dictionary<string, IRoute> handlers = new Dictionary<string, IRoute> {
        { "route_1", new MyRoute() }
    };
    public void OnMessage(string json)
    {
        var message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Message>(json);
        if (handlers.TryGetValue(message.Route, out var handler))
            handler.OnMessage(message.Data);
    }
}
```